# How can I set up ALSA on VDS?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, alsa, vds

Greetings to everyone.

I'm trying to convert SWF to MP4 using dump-gnash and ffmpeg.

But the problem is the dump-gnash won't create raw video without ALSA set up properly.

Here is a part of dump-gnash log:

`ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Killed`

I readed about ALSA and learned is't a sound card handler tool.

But I don't have any sound cards on my VDS. Then there is a question: **how can i set up ALSA on VDS and make it work?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Tell your program to use the ALSA device named `null`.

If that does not work, try loading the `snd-dummy` driver.

Comment: Any advice how to point null ALSA device to `dump-gnash` would be nice :)